# Does getchar() function has it's own buffer to store remaining input?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am going through the "C Programming Book" by K&R.
Now the code for the function "getint()" is as follows :-->

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufp = 0;

int getch(void) {
    return (bufp > 0)?buf[--bufp]:getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c) {
    if(bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}

int getint(int *pn) {
    int c, sign;

    while(isspace(c = getch()));

    if(!isdigit(c) && c != EOF && c != '-' && c != '+') {
        ungetch(c);
        return 0;
    }

    sign = (c == '-')?-1:1;
    if(c == '+' || c == '-')
        c = getch();

    *pn = 0;
    while(isdigit(c)) {
        *pn = (*pn * 10) + (c - '0');
        c = getch();
    }

    *pn *= sign;

    if(c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);


    return c;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int r, i;

    while((r = getint(&i)) != EOF)
        if(r != 0)
            printf("res: %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I don't get the step by step working procedure of this function, even though I tried to run it theoretically on a paper.

And the fact that when I input "23". how does it converted to 23 , I know there is the logic to convert "23" to 23 but c = getch() doesn't store the remaining "3" in the buffer after input then how does it get back the 3, during the conversion. 
Does getchar() have it's own buffer where it stores all the inout characters and fetch them 1 by 1. 
Any help is highly appriciated.

Comment: Getch catch each input keyboard and store it in the buffer

Comment: `getchar()` is just like `getc(stdin)` and `stdin` is a default `FILE *` in `stdio.h`. These are buffered.

Comment: We are not a tutoring site. Maybe you have skipped some chapters or should read some other book. K&R expects some basic Unix/computing basics knowledge. It is also outdated wrt C language since 18 years. Get a book covering modern C11 (at least C99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet you provided, the main logic is here:

```
1. *pn = 0;
2. while(isdigit(c)) {
3.     *pn = (*pn * 10) + (c - '0');
4.     c = getch();
5. }
```

The `pn` is a buffer that will hold the final value of integer and `c` is the char that is read each time, one by one, by `getchar()`. So, when you are reading  in a "23", here's what is happening:

1. `'2'` was read onto `c`
2. `pn = 0; c = '2';` on line 3 (from the snippet with main logic) we multiply by 10 the value in buffer and add (`0x32 - 0x30`)
3. `pn = 2; c = 2;`
4. read `'3'` onto `c`
5. multiplying `pn` by `10` gives you `20`, you add (`0x33 - 0x30`) and you have the final 23.

Things to keep in mind:

- `getchar()` reads chars one by one from stdin
- adding simple `printf()` statements would help you in understanding the flow of your program
- try to run it under gdb, examine values of variables

Answer (score 1):

> And the fact that when I input "23". how does it converted to 23 , I know there is the logic to convert "23" to 23 but c = getch() doesn't store the remaining "3" in the buffer after input then how does it get back the 3, during the conversion. Does getchar() have it's own buffer where it stores all the inout characters and fetch them 1 by 1.

From this, I read that you expect `getch()` to somehow receive your whole line of input. Well, that's wrong.

First a quick side-note about the `getchar()` vs `getch()` confusion here. In *standard* C, `getch()` requires an argument of type `FILE *`. This is a *stream*. `getchar()` is equivalent to `getch(stdin)`. The code shown here seems to be pre-standard C. I assume any occurence of `getch()` should really be `getchar()`.

What you have to know is that `stdio.h` `FILE *` *streams* are buffered. There are different modes (no buffering, line buffering and full buffering) available.

`stdin` is your *default input stream*. It will typically come from the keyboard (but your program doesn't care about that, it could be redirected to come from a file, pipe, etc). The default buffering mode of `stdin` is **line buffered**.

So what happens when you input `23 <enter>` is that the `2` will only go in the *input buffer* of `stdin`, as well as the `3`, and only when a newline follows (pressing the enter key, this is the character `\n`), there's finally something available to read on `stdin`.

`getchar()` doesn't care about buffering. It reads from `stdin`, waiting until there is something available to read. Then it reads **a single character**, so if there are more characters in `stdin`'s input buffer, they **will stay there** until read by `getchar()` or *any other function* reading from `stdin`.

Comment: in the code snippet the getch() is just a wrapper for getchar(), so according to your assumption - each getch() is actually a getchar() here ;)

Comment: Ah, see it now, manual implementation of `ungetch()` ... well the point is buffering happens in the `stdio` stream, I hope that was the source of OP's confusion :)